# Database only Running total with with conditions

Tags: postgresql, cumulative-sum

There are a ton of questions about calculating running totals with Postgres but I am struggling to do something slightly different.

I have a table that looks like this

| txn_id | amount |
| --- | --- |
| String | Integer |

`amounts` can either be positive or negative.

I am trying to return a table that looks like this

| txn_id | amount | running_total | overage_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| String | Integer | Integer | Integer |

Where running total is running sum of the `amount` column as long as the amount is greater than zero and `overage_total` is the running sum of amounts that were lower than zero.

An example of would be

| txn_id | amount |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | -4 |
| d | 2 |
| e | -1 |

I have been using a window function for the running sum but it's not quite what we need.

The correct table would return

| txn_id | amount | running_total | overage_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| b | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| c | -4 | 0 | 1 |
| d | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| e | -1 | 1 | 1 |

Currently I have am doing this in code but it would be really incredible to do it in the database if it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

An option is to use a function to step through the rows and do calculations:

```
CREATE FUNCTION runningTotalWithCondition() RETURNS TABLE(txn_id char(1), amount int, running_total integer, overage_total integer) AS
$$

DECLARE 

running_total integer := 0;
overage_total integer := 0;
c CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY txn_id ASC;

BEGIN
    
    FOR recordvar IN c LOOP
      IF (running_total + recordvar.amount) > 0 THEN
        running_total = running_total + recordvar.amount;
        overage_total = overage_total;
      ELSE 
        overage_total = overage_total + abs(running_total + recordvar.amount);
        running_total = 0;
      END IF;
    
      RETURN QUERY SELECT recordvar.txn_id, recordvar.amount, running_total, overage_total;
    END LOOP;

END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Calling the function:

```
SELECT * FROM runningTotalWithCondition();
```

Comment: Look up window functions.  They exist to solve cumulative sum problems and similar running total calculations - I give this as a SQL interview question.

Comment: Yes I know, but this is a special running total calculation (with a condition), I didn't find a better way to solve it.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-conditional.html and window functions https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html - update your answer and I will give it an upvote

Comment: The issue with window functions is they do not group. I have been using a window function but it's not quite right

Comment: @austinbv I don't understand what you mean when you say, "window functions [...] do not group."  Window functions are literally aggregate functions. They operate on groups by their very definition. The PARTITION BY clause dynamically creates a streaming group. This is a direct result of the fact grouping == synchronization and synchronization == counting in set theory/logic programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern here is running total with a cap. It could be achieved with recursive cte:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte_r AS (
  SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.txn_id) AS rn FROM tab t
), cte AS (
  SELECT rn,
         txn_id,
         amount, 
         CASE WHEN amount <= 0 THEN 0 ELSE amount END AS total,
         CASE WHEN amount <= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS overage_total
  FROM cte_r
  WHERE rn = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cte_r.rn,
         cte_r.txn_id,
         cte_r.amount,
         CASE WHEN cte.total + cte_r.amount <= 0 THEN 0 
                        ELSE cte.total + cte_r.amount 
                   END AS total,
         cte.overage_total + CASE WHEN cte.total + cte_r.amount <= 0 
                                  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS overage_total
  FROM cte
  JOIN cte_r
    ON cte.rn = cte_r.rn-1
)
SELECT txn_id, amount, total,overage_total
FROM cte
ORDER BY rn;
```

Output:

```
+---------+---------+--------+---------------+
| txn_id  | amount  | total  | overage_total |
+---------+---------+--------+---------------+
| a       |      1  |     1  |             0 |
| b       |      2  |     3  |             0 |
| c       |     -4  |     0  |             1 |
| d       |      2  |     2  |             1 |
| e       |     -1  |     1  |             1 |
| f       |      2  |     3  |             1 |
| h       |     -4  |     0  |             2 |
+---------+---------+--------+---------------+
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8314e90c160d258d8920f3cd0a0ee94d)**

---

Related: [Conditional SUM on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52936314/5070879) and [7. Capping a running total](https://blog.jooq.org/10-sql-tricks-that-you-didnt-think-were-possible/)