# How to query SUM() Window Function with a Limit? SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions, recursive-query

Im looking to recreate the SUM_FUNC_LIMIT column below where a subtraction occurs but is limited to reaching 0.

A SUM() window function will recreate SUM_FUNC, but I cannot create the SUM_FUNC_LIMIT column.

*EXCEL FORMULA is =IF(D1+B2<0,0,D1+B2)*

| ROW [A] | AMOUNT [B] | SUM_FUNC [C] | SUM_FUNC_LIMIT [D] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 2 | 9 | 14 | 14 |
| 3 | -6 | 8 | 8 |
| 4 | -6 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | -6 | -4 | 0 |
| 6 | 3 | -1 | 3 |
| 7 | -6 | -7 | 0 |
| 8 | -6 | -13 | 0 |
| 9 | 7 | -6 | 7 |
| 10 | 3 | -3 | 10 |
| 11 | -6 | -9 | 4 |

Any help appreciated.

Have tried many things... but calling a previous entry within a new entry is not possible in SQL.

Comment: Looks like [Capping a running total](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53994970/5070879) case which could be achieved using [MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/match_recognize)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda, could you please elaborate on how to use this function for his purpose? I'm unable to decipher from documentation and there is nothing open-source

Comment: The idea is to use MATCH_RECOGNIZE and pattern that "resets" the running total when it hits 0. **[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/rzQSRv0I)** As of time of writing it seems that this pattern is not possible for Snowflake due to  functions that are [supported on DEFINE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/match_recognize#limitations-on-window-functions-used-in-define-and-measures)

Answer (score 0):

As far as concerns, you can't implement this logic with window functions, you would typically need a recursive query. For table with a structure like `mytable(rn, amount)`, where `rn` starts at `1`, you could phrase it as:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select 0 as rn, 0 as amount, 0 as sum_func, 0 as sum_func_limit
    union all
    select t.rn, t.amount, t.amount + c.sum_func, greatest(t.amount + c.sum_func, 0) 
    from cte c
    inner join mytable t on t.rn = c.rn + 1
)
select * from cte where rn > 0
```

Comment: Thanks very much GMB, I've managed to achieve the result because of your response. 

Noting I think you meant (but it works with the edit):
    select t.rn, t.amount, t.amount + c.sum_func, greatest(t.amount + c.sum_func_limit, 0)